# Filter nfc tag urls using the <data> element in the manifest?

Tags: android

I have a nexus-s, and I have an nfc tag with the following data written into it:

```
http://www.example.com/abc
```

When the tag is discovered by the nexus-s, I get a list of two applications that can handle a tag read:

```
tags (included with the nexus-s I think)
MyTagReadingApp (my own demo app)
```

This is the manifest for my demo app:

```
<activity 
  android:name=".activities.ActivityReadTag" 
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So my app gets invoked any time *any* nfc tag is read. I want it to only appear in the list of apps that can handle a tag read if there is a url data in the tag and it is part of my particular www.example.com domain. Something like:

```
<activity 
  android:name=".activities.ActivityReadTag" 
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
      android:scheme="http"
      android:host="www.example.com"
      android:pathPattern="/" />

  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I was hoping the  tag would work here, but doesn't seem to. This technique works for urls elsewhere like for hyperlinks. Not sure if the sdk supports this yet?

Thank you

--------- Update ---------------

Looking at DDMS, I see the following when making contact with the tag:

```
Starting: Intent { 
  act=android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED 
  dat=http://example.com/foo/1234 flg=0x10000000 (has extras) 
} from pid 246

Starting: Intent { 
  flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.nfc3/com.android.nfc.TechListChooserActivity 
  (has extras) 
} from pid 246
```

so I tried updating my manifest to:

```
<activity 
  android:name=".activities.ActivityReadTag" 
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">

  <intent-filter>
    <action
      android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
```

still no luck though. I'm using api 10 (2.3.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange it works fine on my nexus S.
Maybe it's this your intent contains

```
    dat=http://example.com/foo/1234 flg=0x10000000 (has extras)
```

however you app wil only respond to WWW.example.com. I created a tag with example.com, and the app didn't respond anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the 
 action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"
otherwise your app won't show up in the appchooser

The rest of the filter looks ok to me